Classes created at runtime suddenly missing properties. Using VB.net in Visual Studio
Something bazzar just happened while I was working on a project.
Some of the classes I declare at runtime started to error.  In my case, the TextBox and the ComboBox.
It is not a coding error for sure, something seams to have happened to the environment for that particular project.
I can start a new project and I can create classes at runtime without a problem, with the same code.
I created a work around for the time being an used a listbox instead, but that is a not a solution.
The initial error was "items" is not a member of ComboBox, which is obviously vey strange.  I wasn't even doing anything to do with the ComboBoxes at the time.
Any insight would be appreciated.

I tried various other classes and some worked fine while others showed problems, in my case the TextBox and the ComboBox classes.
I have tried searching online for anyone who has experienced the same problem, but because of the nature of the problem, it is tricky to express in a search, and all my attempts to find something fail.

Visual Studio does that sometimes, when automatically inferring the Types used in a Project. Remove the Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles line it probably added at the top of the file. Or comment it out, it may prevent the import from being added again in the future

Ahh man, THANK YOU so much, it had me going the whole day.

Now my toolbar icons have disappeared, is that part of the similar problem?

I'm not sure what a toolbar is here. Do you mean the ancient / deprecated ToolBar Control? That uses an ImageList for the Icons, VisualStyles are not involved. If it's a ToolStrip (the Control that replaced the ToolBar a long while ago), that also doesn't require any explicit reference to VisualStyles -- If you have created, let's say manually, Controls that you have then added to a ToolBar Control, that could be. But I don't know anything about your code or what you're doing there

Be nice now Jimi....we all have our problems
I was always a VB guy...then got married...now divorce...and back in the game.
